# Rational numbers inequality proof - is this proof valid?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

> Knowing that $x^2+y^2 = 2 $ prove that $x+y \le 2$

I rewrite this as
$$x^2+y^2 \ge x+y$$
Now, multiply both sides by 2
$$x^2 -2x + 1 + y^2-2y + 1 -2 +x^2 + y^2 \ge 0$$
I substitue $2$ for $x^2+y^2$
$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2\ge0$$
Which is true

Comment: Now it's true! I fixed your post.

Comment: I don't understand how you obtain the second line multiplying everything by $2$.

Comment: @Bernard
$x^2 + x^2   + y^2 + y^2 - 2x - 2y  + 1 + 1 - 2 \ge 0$
Now I group the terms to get this expression.

Comment: Um, your very first line you assume what you want to proof and then you ... don't get a contradiction.  That's not a proof. So what if you get something is true?  If polar bears lived in the middle of the Indian Ocean then all they would have to eat is fish.  So polar bears would eat fish.  Which is true; polar bear *do* eat fish.  Therefore polar bears live in the Indian Ocean... because they eat fish... which they'd have to do if they lived in the Indian Ocean... so they do....

Comment: An alternative to Hagen's proof below is to use differentiability: every point on the circle is $(x,y)=(\sqrt2\cos t,\sqrt2\sin t)$ for some $t$ hence one must show that $f(t)\leqslant\sqrt2$, where $f(t)=\cos t+\sin t$. The derivative of $f$ is such that $f'(t)=\cos t-\sin t$ hence $f(t)$ is maximum at $t=\pi/4$ and $f(\pi/4)=\sqrt2$, qed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is insecure and accidentally.
When a line $x+y=t$ is tangent to circle, t is max or minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Or (shortened, once we know how to poceed):
$$x+y\le x+y+\tfrac{ (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}2=x+y+\tfrac{x^2-2x+1+y^2-2y+1}2=\frac{x^2+y^2+2}2=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$(1+1)(x^2+y^2)\ge(x+y)^2 \Rightarrow (x+y)^2\le4 \Rightarrow |x+y|\le2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Geometric method, inspired by Takahiro Waki's answer:

Let $\Gamma$ be a circle centered at $C$ and $P$ be any point on $\Gamma$. Let $L$ be a line passing through $C$, and let $H$ lie on $L$ so that $PH$ is perpendicular to $L$. Then $CHP$ is a triangle with a perpendicular angle opposite to $CP$.

Let $Q$ be the point on $L$ so that $HQ$ and $PH$ have the same length and $Q$ is farther to $C$ than to $H$. We notice that $Q$ must lie outside of the circle $\Gamma$, for the length of $CQ$, being as the sum of the legs of $\triangle CHP$, must exceed that of $CP$, a radius of the circle. As such, $L$ must intersect $\Gamma$ somewhere between $H$ and $Q$, at which point I shall call $N$. As well, $L$ intersects the circle at yet another point, which I shall call $K$. However, as $\triangle CHP$ contains a perpendicular angle, so must $\triangle PHQ$, namely, on the other side of the intersection of $PH$ with $L$.

Now, $PQ$ is either a tangent of $\Gamma$, in which place $P$ will be the point of tangency, or it might intersect $\Gamma$ somewhere between $P$ and $Q$, which I shall call by $M$. Here $PM$ must be of lesser quantity than $PQ$, the area of the square on which being double that of the square on $PH$.

Interpreting $M$ to coincide with $P$ in the scenario of tangency, the product of the lengths $PM$ and$ PQ$ shall coincide with that of the lengths $QN$ and $QK$. Then $QN$ together with $CN$ forms the segment $CQ$, which in turn forms $QK$ with a radius of the circle $CK$.

Hence, the product as given above shall not exceed the area of the square on PQ, albeit in scenario of tangency they will be equal. If this product, in its second presentation as aforementioned, is put as the product of the sums and differences of the quantities $CQ$ and a radius $CN$, I shall in another way put it as the differences of the areas of the squares on those quantities.

Since the quantity of $CN$, being a radius of the circle $\Gamma$, has a sqaure on which whose area is determined by the circle, the product as before may be given solely by the length of $CQ$, and furthermore by the area of the square on $CQ$. However, from what precedes, this area may at most be the sum of areas of the squares on $PQ$ and $CP$, the quantities being equal only when $PQ$ is put as a tangent of $\Gamma$ at $P$.

In such scenario, the triangles $CHP$ and $PHQ$, both being triangles with a perpendicular angle with two sides of equal length and sharing the side $PH$, is necessarily congruent to one another. Thus, the squares on $PQ$ and $CP$ are of the same area, for the segments themselves are of the same length. Then the area of the square on $CQ$ is double that of the square on either $CP$ or $PQ$, whose quantity shall be exceeded by no other choice of the point $P$, provided the measurements of the circle $\Gamma$ is left unaltered.

Finally, I shall put the area of the square on $CP$ to be 2. Then in the scenario of tangency, that of the square on $CQ$ shall be double of that, or $4$. Therefore, the length of $CQ$, being as well the sum of the lengths of $CH$ and $HQ$, or equally  that of $CH$ and $PH$, shall be 2. That is to say, the sum of the lengths of $CH$ and $PH$ may not exceed 2.

Q.E.D.

("Translation")

$HQ=PH, QC\gt QH, CQ=CH+PH\gt CP$

$PM\lt PQ, PQ^2=2PH^2$

$(PM)(PQ)=(QN)(QK), QN=CQ-CN, QK=CQ+CK$

$(QN)(QK)\le PQ^2, (QN)(QK)=(CQ-CN)(CQ+CK)=(CQ-CN)(CQ+CN)=CQ^2-CN^2$

$CQ^2\le PQ^2+CP^2$

$PQ=CP, CQ^2\le 2CP^2=2PQ^2$

$CP^2=2, CQ^2=2CP^2=4, CQ=CH+HQ=CH+PH=2, CH+PH\le 2$